# Mod_wsgi daemon process status

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-wsgi

Is there a way to get the status of the mod_wsgi daemon processes and threads? Something like apache's server status page.

My server's taking a while to respond sometimes and I want to see if it's because all the daemon threads are busy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some new features are being worked on for mod_wsgi 4.0 which will help with this. Other than that, production performance monitoring tools like New Relic can also be used to a degree. You do though need to add some additional Apache configuration so New Relic can see queuing time.

You are better off following the mod_wsgi mailing list and asking about what is possible there.

You can get an idea of some of what is being worked on by reading:

https://plus.google.com/114657481176404420131/posts/G1jM6WW3Pnu

Answer (score 1):

Just check the documentation of [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives). Short answer: No.